# Project Merging Without Version Control

Tags: git

A while ago, I copied a project directory onto an external server. Over time, the project on the external server has diverged from the original on my computer.

I just downloaded the external project again and would like to merge it with the original and put the merged project under version control.

What is the best way to accomplish this with Git?

Comment: How about letting current state of original repo into git repository and then overwriting its contents with external project files so that you can see what changed on diff and act accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git init
git add .
git commit
git checkout -b t
# copy remote files, overwriting when nencessary
git add .
git commit
git checkout master
git merge t
git branch -d t
```

Depending on differences between versions it may go well or produce whole lot of conflicts, which will be reported after merge command.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set up a new remote, e.g.:

```
git remote add original git://original_url
```

After this you can just `git pull <remote> <branch>` from the external one. For example, if the remote is named origin and the branch is master, you just do:

```
git pull origin master
```

This will pull down the changes, merge them and show the conflicts (if any).

---

You can try different strategies according to how many conflicts you get; for example you may consider rebasing instead.